# trigger script when object content is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to enable a button when the object src is changed.
So far this is the code that I was trying to use but I don't know why it wouldn't work.

```
<object id="obj" type="text/html" width="100%" height="500px" onchange="$('#btvoltar').attr({'style':'display:normal'});"></object>
```

and also

```
<button type="button" style="display:none" id="btvoltar" onclick="window.history.back()" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Voltar</button>
```

Comment: How are you setting the `src` of the object? I'd suggest manually raising an event there, otherwise using something like a MutationObserver - although that should be a last resort

Comment: sorry I mean data attribute

Comment: Same question applies

Comment: $('#obj').attr({'data':'url'});

Comment: In which case I'd suggest adding a `trigger()` to raise an event manually, eg. `trigger('data-changed')`, which you can hook to unobtrusively and performa whatever logic you need: `$('object').on('data-changed', function() { /* do something... */ });`

Comment: thanks, it kinda worked for now. I'll try to adjust my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:block`  , there is nothing called `display:normal`